# JSON schema validation with Java API

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I am not interested in validating JSON documents against JSON schema.
I would like to validate JSON schema itself, check whether it is valid against a specific draft.
Are there tools Java that would validate schema itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON Schema (in JSON format) is nothing else but another JSON document.
What you're describing is exactly what Meta Schemas are for.

That means any library for validating JSON documents against a JSON Schema can be used to validate a JSON Schema against a respective Draft's Meta Schema. Examples for available Java libraries are listed on [json-schema.org/implementations.html](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-java)

Meta Schemas are published alongside the specification on [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/specification.html#meta-schemas)